# How to create 3D text that is animated (comes from background into forefront)

Tags: psychopy

I am not proficient at programming as I am just learning. I have to create a novel experiment and desire to know how to create 3D text images in PsychoPy with the builders model. PsychoPy is on a Windows 8.1 laptop with the standalone version 1.83.01. Please keep all responses as lay-person as possible. I also desire to understand how to animate the 3D images coming from the background into the forefront of the screen.

Thank you for your valuable time,
Death

Comment: To add to Mike's answer below, you'd have to use a different python module for 3D visualizatioin. Look at VPython and this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026134/python-3d-visualization-and-graphics

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use PsychoPy Builder to create 3D stimuli like this. The normal model would be to create them externally in other 3D animation software and export them to a movie. In PsychoPy Builder, you would then play that movie as required.

PsychoPy Builder can be used to scale 2D stimuli progressively, so you could have text that appears to "zoom in" from a distance. But I suspect you want something more than this.