# slicing volume rendering graph in python

Tags: python, visualization, slice, volume, 4d

I have an input data with each row having (x,y,z,data), i.e., each coordinate (x,y,z) has a value "data". I would like to make a slicing volumetric graph like below in python. I am new to python, any tips would be much appreciated. [see here for the example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fenuS.png)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026134/python-3d-visualization-and-graphics) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data organized as a 2D array (n-points x 4) [x,y,z,data] (this can also be refered to as a point-cloud representations) and you want to display it as a volume rendering. You have to first resample it as a 3D array ([interpolate 3D volume with numpy and or scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836067/interpolate-3d-volume-with-numpy-and-or-scipy)) and then create an isosurface using marching cubes ([How to display a 3D plot of a 3D array isosurface in matplotlib mplot3D or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030098/how-to-display-a-3d-plot-of-a-3d-array-isosurface-in-matplotlib-mplot3d-or-simil))

You can also plot the values using a 3D scatter plot which is much easier, but won't get you the kind of plot you asked for (https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html)